# AngularFire2 nested *ngFor Array within Array... but Firebase doesn't have arrays...?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nested, angularfire2, ngfor

I'm using AngularFire2, trying to get lists out of lists.
A nested *ngFor within an *ngFor doesn't show on the view...

app.componnent

```
...
constructor(private _af: AngularFire) {
    this.lists = this._af.database.list(this._API_URL);
}
...
```

app.component.html

```
<div *ngFor="let list of lists | async">
    {{sublist.name}}<br/> <!-- I can see you -->

    <!--******* I can't see you **********-->
    <div *ngFor="let rootword of list.rootwords">
        {{rootword.word}} {{rootword.total}}
    </div> 
</div>
```

Example of Firebase

```
maindb
  |_list1
  |  |_name: 'List 1"
  |  |_rootwords
  |     |_apple
  |     |   |_word: 'apple'
  |     |   |_total: 4
  |     |
  |     |_banana
  |     |   |_word: 'banana'
  |     |   |_total: 2
  |     |_carpet 
  |     |   |_word: 'carpet'
  |     |   |_total: 21
  |
  |_list2
     |_name: "List 2"
     |_rootwords
        |_elephant
        |    |_word: 'elephant'
        |    |_total: 4
        |_sloth
             |_word: 'sloth
             |_total: 5
```

How do you nest an ngFor in an ngFor with firebase.list ??
Do I need to map or filter?
Does AngularFire2 have a way to convert the inner object to an array?

All suggestions appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace the `rootwords` object with an array using the [`map` opererator](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-map) and [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), like this:

```ts
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

constructor(private _af: AngularFire) {

  this.lists = this._af.database
    .list(this._API_URL)

    // Use map the map operator to replace each item in the list:

    .map(list => list.map(item => ({

      // Map to a new item with all of the item's properties:
      ...item,

      // And replace the rootwords with an array:
      rootwords: Object.keys(item.rootwords)

        // Use reduce to build an array of values:
        .reduce((acc, key) => [...acc, item.rootwords[key]], [])
      })
    ));
}
```

Or, without the spread syntax:

```ts
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

constructor(private _af: AngularFire) {

  this.lists = this._af.database
    .list(this._API_URL)
    .map(list => list.map(item => {
        var copy = Object.assign({}, item);
        copy.rootwords = Object.keys(item.rootwords).reduce((acc, key) => {
            acc.push(item.rootwords[key]);
            return acc;
        }, []);
        return copy;
    }));
}
```

Comment: Didn't work... starting at ...item, getting an error Property Assignment expected.. Do I have to import another rxjs to use this syntax?

But commenting that out, still get error:
ViewWrappedError 
Error: Error in ./LearnComponent class LearnComponent - inline template:19:17 caused by: Invalid argument '[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],...' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'
    at ViewWrappedError.ZoneAwareError (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:1150:33)
    at ViewWrappedError.BaseError [as constructor] ...

Comment: Commented out second | async,  now  Error -  Property assignment expected. caused still by ...item

Comment: What version of TypeScript are you using?

Comment: TypeScript v2.1.1

Comment: If I manually add the item keys, it works and remove the inner | async pipe.

Comment: The spread syntax should be valid for 2.1, see [*Object Spread and Rest*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html). Anyway, I've added a non-spread version.

Comment: Too bad the spread operator doesn't work for some reason. Would be a very elegant fix...